# Blend 4 vs Visual Studio 2010 vector rendering

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, blend

I have a really rare problem. I have a .AI file with vectors. When I import some vector to Expression Blend 4 I saw the vector really good, but, when I copy the XAML code to Visual Studio (COPY&PASTE) the image is really BAD.

Icon Code:

```
<Canvas x:Key="FloatingWindowCloseIcon" Height="18.081" Width="18.077" x:Shared="false">
        <Canvas.CacheMode>
            <BitmapCache EnableClearType="True" RenderAtScale="2.0" />
        </Canvas.CacheMode>
        <Path Data="F1M20.9619,11.8481C15.9699,11.8481,11.9229,15.8951,11.9229,20.8881C11.9229,25.8791,15.9699,29.9291,20.9619,29.9291C25.9529,29.9291,29.9999,25.8791,29.9999,20.8881C29.9999,15.8951,25.9529,11.8481,20.9619,11.8481 M20.9619,13.2251C25.1869,13.2251,28.6229,16.6651,28.6229,20.8881C28.6229,25.1151,25.1869,28.5521,20.9619,28.5521C16.7359,28.5521,13.2999,25.1151,13.2999,20.8881C13.2999,16.6651,16.7359,13.2251,20.9619,13.2251" Fill="#FFF4F4F4" Height="18.081" Canvas.Left="0" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="0" Width="18.077"/>
        <Path Data="F1M25.377,18.4185L23.431,16.4705L20.962,18.9395L18.493,16.4705L16.546,18.4185L19.015,20.8865L16.546,23.3555L18.493,25.3025L20.962,22.8355L23.431,25.3025L25.377,23.3555L22.908,20.8865z" Fill="#FFF4F4F4" Height="8.832" Canvas.Left="4.75" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="4.624" Width="8.831"/>
    </Canvas>
```

Here some screenshots:

[image: This is Expression Blend 4]

[image: This is Visual Studio 2010 result]

Comment: Could you perchance include the XAML?

Comment: especially the DATA or IconData mini-language query please (that long burst of numbers on the screen)